# Screenshot appears in iTunesConnect and not on Appstore

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, screenshot, app-store-connect

I have uploaded few screenshots along with binary. Now,app status is **Ready for Sale** but **screenshot has not been updated** yet. I have taken screenshot from *iPhone 6 simulator* (seems this is not an issue since several apps are available with screenshots taken from simulator).

**New screenshot appears in iTunes Connect but does not appears on AppStore**. Why is this so?

Answer (score 2):

It can often take many hours to update the binary and screen shots when the app version has updated. The servers they use are load balanced so it may be that some people see the updated image and some don't. If you're on Wi-Fi, see if you can check on a different connection or cellular as you might see a different result... If not then just be patient.